# OnTouchListener not working

Tags: java, android

I have a few buttons in a tab layout for which the OnClickListener works fine. The purpose of these buttons is to start a new activity when clicked upon. I want my code to work for the touch mode of the phone as well. In other words I wanted to know how to implement the OnTouchListener for the code. Currently I have something like

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  startActivity(new Intent().setClass(this, OtherActivity.class));
  return true;
}
```

I am just thinking about it the same way as I would think about the onClick() method but apparently I am wrong.

Any help in this matter would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: I believe your OnClickListener is sufficient, for touch mode as well.  But maybe I don't understand.  Do you mean that you want the activity to change on (the equivalent of) MouseDown (instead of MouseUp - a Click is MouseDown followed by MouseUp)?

Comment: Also - you are not being selective about which MotionEvents you want to process.  You might want to say something along the lines of `if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)...`

Comment: I thought onClick would be sufficient too but it doesn't work for touch events. So if I understand you right then I'm supposed to check for both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP and then invoke the activity? And yeah I am not being selective about the MotionEvents because all I want it to do is to be able to click on it.

Comment: Eastman if you arent selective and your on touch starts working. You would have two activities started one in  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEVent.ACTION_UP. Also try setting focussable, focussableInTouchMode and clickable to true for your button. OnTouch should work. If not post you code i mean layout file and where you set the touchlistener.

Answer (score 0):

Touching a button on the screen should generate click events the same as using a hardware keypad. Try using the Log object and LogCat to see when methods are called.